# How can I identify conflicting code in code blocks on Squarespace?

Tags: html, squarespace

I'm setting up a Squarespace website, and I use code blocks for features I can't build on the platform. For instance I found a gallery that works better on mobile, so I want to use that. It works fine with one, but when I insert two on the same page, the code blocks seem to conflict with each other, so only one works.

The same thing happens, when I use two very different code blocks, something in one of them seems to conflict with the other one.
Any good pieces of advice for how to handle this? Maybe rename some identical elements there might be across the blocks, so names become unique?

Example of gallery code, one works fine, two on the same page doesn't.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>W3.CSS</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<style>
.mySlides {display:none;}
</style>
<body>
<div class="w3-content w3-display-container">
  <img class="mySlides" src="https://images.com/car.jpg" style="width:100%">
 <img class="mySlides" src="https://images.com/cat.jpg" style="width:100%">
 <img class="mySlides" src="https://images.com/apple.jpg" style="width:100%">
 <img class="mySlides" src="https://images.com/hat.jpg" style="width:100%">


  <button class="w3-button w3-black w3-display-left" onclick="plusDivs(-1)">&#10094;</button>
  <button class="w3-button w3-black w3-display-right" onclick="plusDivs(1)">&#10095;</button>
</div>

<script>
var slideIndex = 1;
showDivs(slideIndex);

function plusDivs(n) {
  showDivs(slideIndex += n);
}

function showDivs(n) {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  if (n > x.length) {slideIndex = 1}
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = x.length} ;
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  x[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
}


var slideIndex = 0;
carousel();

function carousel() {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  slideIndex++;
  if (slideIndex > x.length) {slideIndex = 1}
  x[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
  setTimeout(carousel, 4000); // Change image every 4 seconds
}
</script>

</body>
</html>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>W3.CSS</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<style>
.mySlides {display:none;}
</style>
<body>
<div class="w3-content w3-display-container">
 <img class="mySlides" src="https://images.com/car.jpg" style="width:100%">
 <img class="mySlides" src="https://images.com/cat.jpg" style="width:100%">
 <img class="mySlides" src="https://images.com/dog.jpg" style="width:100%">
 <img class="mySlides" src="https://images.com/apple.jpg" style="width:100%">


  <button class="w3-button w3-black w3-display-left" onclick="plusDivs(-1)">&#10094;</button>
  <button class="w3-button w3-black w3-display-right" onclick="plusDivs(1)">&#10095;</button>
</div>

<script>
var slideIndex = 1;
showDivs(slideIndex);

function plusDivs(n) {
  showDivs(slideIndex += n);
}

function showDivs(n) {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  if (n > x.length) {slideIndex = 1}
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = x.length} ;
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  x[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
}


var slideIndex = 0;
carousel();

function carousel() {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  slideIndex++;
  if (slideIndex > x.length) {slideIndex = 1}
  x[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
  setTimeout(carousel, 4000); // Change image every 4 seconds
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, that particular solution is designed to only be used once on a page. It is crudely and very simplistically written to demonstrate some basic ideas and in fact makes use of techniques that are not best-practice (which I say only to reinforce that it is written to convey overall concepts and not for advanced implementation). As a result, it is correspondingly quite difficult to minimally adapt the code to accommodate multiple instances of it on a single page. I'm afraid it may well be faster, easier and better to rewrite it entirely (which is beyond what a typical answer on StackOverflow would include).

In general, however, if you really wanted to try to adapt that particular solution to support multiple instances on a single page (not recommended, as it is likely to cause frustration, but if your into it) you could:

**1) Remove unnecessary code.** Anywhere where you have copy/pasted the code as you showed in your question, remove these six lines at the beginning:

`<!DOCTYPE html>`
`<html>`
`<title>W3.CSS</title>`
`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">`

`<body>`

And these two lines at the end:

`</body>`
`</html>`

You do that because such code is already accounted for on your website before you added the code blocks. That is, by leaving them in, you're including lines that should not exist in the code block.

**2) Update certain lines of code in each copy of the code.** There are four lines you need to update whenever you create a second, third, etc copy of the code. They are:

`.mySlides {display:none;}`
`<img class="mySlides" ...` (for every image you include)
`var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");` (inside of showDivs function)
`var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides")` (inside of carousel function)

Any time you make another copy of the code on the same page, you need to change `mySlides` to something else, like `mySlides2`. If you had three galleries on a single page, the third copy of the code would use `mySlides3`, and so forth.

And then, you'd update the function names in a similar fashion (adding a number to the end, `plusDivs2`, `showDivs2`, etc.) for each copy of the code you put on the page and similarly update where each of the functions is referenced/called (such as in the button `onclick` attribute).

Finally, you'd update `var slideIndex` to `var slideIndex2`, etc. as applicable within each instance of the code, in the same manner.

Doing the above would, in theory, allow the code to be used multiple times on the page. As I said, there are a number of things undesirable about such an approach, but I wanted to make sure I answered your actual question directly, even if it's not advised.

Comment: Thanks for your incredibly generous reply, I really appreciate it.